# Python: Converting datetime to ordinal

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a list(actually a column in pandas DataFrame if this matters) of Timestamps and I'm trying to convert every element of the list to ordinal format. So I run a for loop through the list(is there a faster way?) and use:

```
import datetime as dt
a = a.toordinal()
```

or

```
import datetime as dt
a = dt.datetime.toordinal(a)
```

however the following happened(for simplicity):

```
In[1]: a
Out[1]: Timestamp('2019-12-25 00:00:00')
In[2]: b = dt.datetime.toordinal(a)
In[3]:b
Out[3]: 737418
In[4]:a = b
In[5]:a
Out[5]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000737418')
```

The result makes absolutely non sense to me. Obviously what I was **trying** to get is:

```
In[1]: a
Out[1]: Timestamp('2019-12-25 00:00:00')
In[2]: b = dt.datetime.toordinal(a)
In[3]:b
Out[3]: 737418
In[4]:a = b
In[5]:a
Out[5]: 737418
```

What went wrong?

[console output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKKWq.png)

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `id(a)` and `id(b)`?

Comment: @AmiTavory they are different

Comment: Yi Fang, in this case I'm guessing you didn't execute `a = b` in the order you think you did.

Comment: Ami, not exactly sure what you mean, I have added a screenshot of console output to the question.

Comment: Could you add to the screenshot `id(a[0])` and `id(b)`?

Comment: Just did, replace the original screenshot.

Comment: Yi Fang, it is clear now. Please note your question, without the screenshot, is somewhat misleading. I've answered to explain why, and what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What went wrong?

Your question is a bit misleading, and the screenshot shows what is going on.

Normally, when you write

```
a = b
```

in Python, it will bind the name `a` to the object bound to `b`. In this case, you will have

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

In your case, however, contrary to your question, you're actually doing the assignment

```
a[0] = b
```

This will call a *method* of `a`, assigning `b` to its 0 index. The object's class determines what happens in this case. Here, specifically, `a` is a `pandas.Series`, and it converts the object in order to conform to its `dtype`.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough and elaborated answer, it clears my "what went wrong?" part. So, how am I supposed to do the desired assignment?

Comment: @YiFang Looking at the screenshot, I'd guess that `a.apply(lambda d: dt.datetime.toordinal(d))` will create a `Series` with your desired result. You can then assign it to a new column.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't loop. It's not necessary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': [datetime(1990, 4, 28),
                             datetime(2018, 4, 13),
                             datetime(2017, 11, 4)]})

print(df)
print(df['dates'].dt.weekday_name)
print(df['dates'].dt.weekday)
print(df['dates'].dt.month)
print(df['dates'].dt.year)
```

gives the dataframe:

```
       dates
0 1990-04-28
1 2018-04-13
2 2017-11-04
```

And the printed values

```
0    Saturday
1      Friday
2    Saturday
Name: dates, dtype: object

0    5
1    4
2    5
Name: dates, dtype: int64

0     4
1     4
2    11
Name: dates, dtype: int64

0    1990
1    2018
2    2017
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

For the toordinal, you need to "loop" with apply:

```
print(df['dates'].apply(lambda x: x.toordinal()))
```

gives the following pandas series

```
0    726585
1    736797
2    736637
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your answer! As mentioned in my original question, I was trying to convert datetime to ordinal, trying to follow your answer but pd.dt doesn's seem to have toordinal()